# jquery cycle function parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

In the below example how do i mention speed in 2nd case  or atleast make it work instantaneously 
`$container.cycle(i, manualEffects[i]);`

Also if i mention effect = none. it doesn't work

```
$(function() { 
    var $bc = $('#buttonContainer'); 

    var $container = $('#container').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollLeft', 
        speed: 300, 
        autostop: 1, 
        autostopCount: 1 
    }); 

    var manualEffects = ['fade','turnUp','curtainY','blindZ','zoom']; 

    $container.children().each(function(i) { 
        $('<input type="button" value="'+(i+1)+'" />') 
            .appendTo($bc).click(function() { 
                // pass fx name as 2nd arg for a one-time override 
                $container.cycle(i, manualEffects[i]); 
                return false; 
            }); 
    }); 

});
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Out This link. I hope you are looking at `FastOnEvent` option

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Answer (score 0):

The speed is controlled by your jquery.cycle.all.js (or minified version) near the mid-bottom of the code:

Underneath:

```
    // override these globally if you like (they are all optional)
    $.fn.cycle.defaults = {
```

You'll see a bunch of settings, including:

```
    timeout:       6000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to   
    disable auto advance)

    speed:         1000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
```

Those are arbitrary numbers -- adjust them for yourself.  Just change timeout to, for instance, 6000, like I have it, for a longer slide.  Then change the transition speed to 1000, for instance, for a quicker transition.  It's pretty simple.